# Hiding elements until load has been completed (ng-cloak isn't what I needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm writing an AngularJS application, but I'm quite new to it, so in the code below, please point out any issues that you have.

I do have my AngularJS application defines like that:

```
var OfficeUIModule = angular.module('OfficeUI', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Then, I do have a couple of services that loads data from various JSon files. 
But i won't post the code here, because I do believe that irrelevant.

Then I do have my controller which basically looks like this:

```
OfficeUIModule.controller('OfficeUIController', function($scope) { });
```

Now, I want the controller to execute some logic on startup and show a DIV element on it.
Here's the case what I want to do:

- Show a `Loading` DIV element during initial setup.
- Show a `Displaying` DIV element when the initialization has been done.

Let's say that in my controller I do have method to initialize the application:

```
OfficeUIModule.controller('OfficeUIController', function($scope) {
    function Init() { 
        // I'll load all the data from the services here.
    }
});
```

In order to call this method on startup, I just define it in my controller like so:

```
OfficeUIModule.controller('OfficeUIController', function($scope) {
    Init();     

    function Init() { 
        // I'll load all the data from the services here.
    }
});
```

And the HTML which I would like to use is the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="loading">LOADING</div>
    <div id="displaying">DISPLAYING</div>
</body>
```

When the page is initially loaded, I would like to show the element 'Loading'.
When the page has been loaded, I would like to show the element 'Displaying'.

In order to make this testable, I've changed my controller method `Init` to include a timeout of 5 seconds, just like below:

```
OfficeUIModule.controller('OfficeUIController', function($scope) {
    Init();     

    function Init() { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Page has been loaded. When you click OK the displaying  DIV should be showed.');
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

So, in this particular case, I would like to make sure that the page is being loaded, displaying the LOADING div and after 5 seconds, display the DISPLAYING div.

I would also like not to see any flickering, and therefore ng-cloak can be used I've read, but I can't manage to configure it correctly.

Here's what I've tried already:

LOADING
    DISPLAYING

However, that setup doesn't work quite well.

I've included a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f03QKN0Jdn6zmwnTUlcl?p=preview) so that you can test the solution you provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you are using `setTimeout` with anonymous function and angularjs isn't aware of model change

http://plnkr.co/edit/FJ2lnrmtG7P3HXZuxRkH?p=preview

if you use angularjs `$timeout` it works

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.initialized = true;
}, 5000);
```

you could also use `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply` to make it work

Comment: And what if I have a service that takes 5 seconds to complete without setTimeout but using a promise. Is angular aware of it then?

Comment: So, just to make sure. If I use ng-cloack and use a service to load my data which takes 5 seconds, the page will stay blank for 5 seconds until the data from the service has been retrieved. Is that correct?

Comment: no, `ng-cloak` will be removed as soon as angularjs bootstrap the page it's not necessary at the same time that service returns data, `ng-cloak` is used ONLY to hide from users parts like `{{myModelHere}}` when the page is bootstraped all those curly brackets notation are changed into watch expressions and evaluated then the `ng-cloak` is removed and user see the page with or without data, if `myModelHere` has no value nothing will be displayed until it gets data. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I'm still a but struggling with the ng-cloak directive. Could you explain me in which situation the usage of ng-cloak is needed? Is it even needed when working with a loading screen as my post mentions?

Comment: I personally rarely use `ng-cloak` as in most of cases my apps load very fast and user won't even see the `{{data}}`, the loading you want to implement works after angular app is bootstraped so IMHO you wont need ng-cloak as it's useless at this stage of userflow

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So ng-cloak is only used to replace the {{}} with empty data, correct? P.S. I've also accepted your answer since this was really what I needed

Comment: `ngCloak` is a css workaround to hide the brackets `{{}}`  before angular is ready, it does not touch model/data in any way, and when angular is ready the ngCloak is disabled and all `{{something}} turned into watch expression that then look for the change to model and as soon as `something` has value on scope it is displayed, i don't know if there is a way to simplify that ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can continue my development right now (until I hit another wall, and they are damn hard to crack :-) )

Comment: I've made a plunker to present what ngCloak is for http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqTDlwflQmPvBGijcsY4?p=preview the app is manually bootstraped after click on button, and before app is ready you can see not cloaked element

Comment: That makes sense. So, it doesn't do anything usefull for me. One question, if I have a list with ng-repeat, is ng-cloak usefull then to only show it when all the elements are rendered?

Comment: No, it's not usefull at the stage when angular is ready and `ng-repeat` works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular version of window load event.

```
angular.element($window).bind('load', function(e) {
    // code to execute
});
```